# XML to google.visualization.DataTable

Tags: xml, datatable, google-visualization

Is there any thing which can convert XML to Google DataTable?

I want to use Google Chart but I think it is the difficult part, converting XML to DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your xml within javascript to json table.
example: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-visualization-api/vddCQ2YKKzc